# Different output depending delete

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char* pass(char* p){
    char* a = new char[10];
    a[0] = 'S';
    a[1] = 'e';
    a[2] = 'r';
    a[3] = 'g';
    a[3] = 'e';
    a[3] = 'y';
    a[4] = '\0';
    p = a;
    //delete [] a;
    return p;
}
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    char* p1 = new char[1000];
    p1[0] = 'G';
    p1[1] = 'e';
    p1[2] = 'r';
    p1[3] = 'y';
    p1[4] = '\0';
    char* p2 = p1;
    cout << p2 << endl;
    cout << pass(p2) << endl;
    delete [] p1;
}
```

and the output is :

```
Gery
Sery
```

but if I uncomment the line `delete [] a`
I got this output :

```
Gery
ê§É
```

Why?

Comment: `p = a;` doesn't copy the values, as you might think.

Comment: You should really brush up on pointers and memory management in C++. It seems there is too much you do not understand for an answer to be effective.

Comment: And this is why you should use `std::stirng` and let the implementation worry about the allocation and copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function

```
char* pass(char* p){
    char* a = new char[10];
    a[0] = 'S';
    a[1] = 'e';
    a[2] = 'r';
    a[3] = 'g';
    a[3] = 'e';
    a[3] = 'y';
    a[4] = '\0';
    p = a;
    //delete [] a;
    return p;
}
```

the parameter is a local variable of the function. After exiting the function it is destroyed.

You can imagine the function and its call the following way

```
pass(p2);

char* pass(/*char* p*/){
    char* p = p2;
    char* a = new char[10];
    a[0] = 'S';
    a[1] = 'e';
    a[2] = 'r';
    a[3] = 'g';
    a[3] = 'e';
    a[3] = 'y';
    a[4] = '\0';
    p = a;
    //delete [] a;
    return p;
}
```

As you see the original pointer `p2` will not be changed in the function. The function changes its local variable `p` that is declared as a parameter.

If to uncomment the delete statement then the memory pointed to by the return value will be deleted and the returned pointer will be invalid. In this case the program has undefined behaviour due to statement

```
cout << pass(p2) << endl;
```

where there is an attempt to access the deleted memory using the return value of the function.

So there is no sense to return pointer to deleted memory.

What you want to do can be achieved in three ways

The first one is to declare the parameter as reference

```
char* pass(char* &p){
           ^^^^^^^^
    char* a = new char[10];
    a[0] = 'S';
    a[1] = 'e';
    a[2] = 'r';
    a[3] = 'g';
    a[3] = 'e';
    a[3] = 'y';
    a[4] = '\0';
    p = a;
    return p;
}
```

and call the function like

```
cout << pass(p2) << endl;
```

The second one is to declare the parameter as pointer to pointer that is to accept the original pointer indirectly

```
char* pass(char* *p){
           ^^^^^^^^
    char* a = new char[10];
    a[0] = 'S';
    a[1] = 'e';
    a[2] = 'r';
    a[3] = 'g';
    a[3] = 'e';
    a[3] = 'y';
    a[4] = '\0';
    *p = a;
    ^^^^^^^^
    return *p;
    ^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

and call the function like

```
cout << pass(&p2) << endl;
```

And at last you could simply assign the returned value to the original pointer. For example

```
char* pass(char* p){
    char* a = new char[10];
    a[0] = 'S';
    a[1] = 'e';
    a[2] = 'r';
    a[3] = 'g';
    a[3] = 'e';
    a[3] = 'y';
    a[4] = '\0';
    p = a;
    return p;
}
```

and call the functionj like

```
cout << ( p2 = pass(p2) ) << endl;
```

though in this case the parameter is obsolete.

In any case you should delete the allocated memory at the end of the program like

```
delete [] p2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = a
```

does not copy the values.

What you are looking for is probably:

```
memcpy(p, a, 10*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: I don’t think this is a helpful answer: First off, it’s not the C++ way of doing things. And it doesn’t actually explain what’s going on. Lastly, even within the context of low-level C++ you wouldn’t write such code (use `std::copy` instead, or at the very least include the proper headers and remove the useless `sizeof(char)`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agrre because the returned pointer in any case will point to deleted memory if to uncomment the delete statement..

Answer (score 0):

Because your uncommented line releases the memory you returned, and your compiler, probably as a debug aid, overwrote the released memory.

Your `p` is passed by value, so `p = a;` does not, in fact, change `p1` inside main. You essentially initialize memory, delete it, and then return a pointer to the deleted memory.

Without the extra delete, you just leak that memory.